# Emacs org-agenda Export agenda -how to?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'am new with Emacs and certainly with lisp.  I know that we can save an agenda (view?) with `C-x C-w`.  Fine but can we do that with the (setq org-agenda-custom-commands) ?  I would like to save the weekly agenda to a `.txt` file (like `agenda.txt`).

Comment: Please don't include more than one question in a single post. I removed your second question - please post it separately. Thx.

Comment: This might get more / better answers at https://emacs.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accounding the documentation of `org-agenda-custom-commands`(partly paste here):

```
Custom commands for the agenda. Each entry is a list like this:

(key desc type match settings files)

or

(key desc (cmd1 cmd2 ...) general-settings-for-whole-set files)

files     A list of files to write the produced agenda buffer to with
          the command org-store-agenda-views.
          If a file name ends in ".html", an HTML version of the buffer
          is written out.  If it ends in ".ps", a postscript version is
          produced.  Otherwise, only the plain text is written to the file.
```

You can set `org-agenda-custom-commands` like:

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      '(("n" "Agenda and all TODOs"
         ((agenda "")
          (alltodo ""))
         nil
         ("~/agenda.txt"))))
```

and then `M-x org-agenda` `n` `M-x org-store-agenda-views` to save the agenda view to `~/agenda.txt`.

or you can write a function to do this.

```lisp
(defun save-agenda-view (&optional arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (org-agenda arg "n")
  (org-store-agenda-views))
```